# Can't view file in parent directories with a script

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, ls

I have a script that looks for files in the present working directories and says if a file is a file or a directory

```
for file in $(ls | sort) ; do
        if [ -d $file ]
        then
                echo "$file is a directory"
        fi
        if [ -f $file ]
        then
                echo "$file is a file"
        fi
done
```

And that works fine. However, when I edit it to view the files in the parent directory I get no output. I changed this

```
for file in $(ls | sort) ; do
```

to this:

```
for file in $(ls .. | sort) ; do
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Hello. It is not recommended parse the output of `ls` within scripts. Try to use the Bash expansion - i.e. `for file in *; ...` or implement `find`. Also in my opinion it is absolutely necessary to quote the variable name especially when you are using the single bracket test within the if statement.

Answer (score 3):

#### Suggestion

Shell globbing for filenames is the most effective and reliable way when listing files and directories in bash … Almost all other external file listing tools are prone to errors e.g. *word splitting* when processing their output **in bash** and they need special care/output formatting and error handling mechanisms implemented in your script to work with them reliably **in bash** … Their output might not be formatted to be ,by default, reliably processable in bash.

Therefore, …

To work on files and directories in the current directory, use:

```bash
for f in *; do
  if [ -d "$f" ]; then
    echo "$f is a directory"
  elif [ -f "$f" ]; then
    echo "$f is a file"
    fi
  done
```

Notice the double quotes(*`"`*)  around the parameter `$f` **must** be used inside the loop’s body(*i.e. between the two command constructs `do … done`*) but **must not** be used in the loop’s head(*i.e. `for f in *;`*).

To work on directories only, use:

```bash
for f in */; do ...
```

To work on parent directory contents, use:

```bash
for f in ../*; do ...
```

Or to limit to directories only in parent directory, use:

```bash
for f in ../*/; do ...
```

Notice that shell filename globbing in bash will be alphabetically and numerically sorted by default.

Notice that the output of `ls` will be sorted by default as well so you don't need to pipe it to `sort` the way you did in your example ... Please also refrain from parsing the output of `ls` that way unless you know the consequences ... Please see [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what to do instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985)

#### Demonstration

To further understand the difference, please see the demonstration below:

Create these four files:

```bash
touch 3_with_tab$'\t'file.txt; touch 1_with_newline$'\n'file.txt; touch '2_with_space file.txt'; touch 4_normal_file.txt
```

List them using shell globbing ... **Works perfectly**:

```bash
for f in *; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a file"; done
1_with_newline
file.txt is a file
2_with_space file.txt is a file
3_with_tab      file.txt is a file
4_normal_file.txt is a file
```

With `find` piped to a `while` loop ... **Fails on filenames containing a new line**:

```bash
find | while IFS= read -r f; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a file"; done
./3_with_tab    file.txt is a file
./4_normal_file.txt is a file
./2_with_space file.txt is a file
```

With `find` in a `for` loop ... **Fails on filenames containing spaces, tabs or newlines**:

```bash
for f in $(find); do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a file"; done
./4_normal_file.txt is a file
```

With `ls` piped to a `while` loop ... **Fails on filenames containing a new line**:

```bash
ls | while IFS= read -r f; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a file"; done
2_with_space file.txt is a file
3_with_tab      file.txt is a file
4_normal_file.txt is a file
```

With `ls` in a `for` loop ... **Fails on filenames containing spaces, tabs or newlines**:

```bash
for f in $(ls); do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a file"; done
4_normal_file.txt is a file
```

#### Mechanisms(*`find` as example*)

If, however, you must use an external file listing tool, then you need to pay attention formatting its output and reading it as input in bash … With `find` for example, your best bet is to use [`find`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man1/find.1.html)'s action `-print0`(*NULL delimited output*) piped to a `while` loop that makes use of [`read`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/readh.html)'s option `-d` to set the input delimiter to NULL using the [`bash`'s ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html) `$'\0'` like so:

```bash
find -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a file"; done
./3_with_tab    file.txt is a file
./4_normal_file.txt is a file
./1_with_newline
file.txt is a file
./2_with_space file.txt is a file
```

Or sorted with [`sort`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man1/sort.1.html)'s option `-z`(*line delimiter is NULL, not newline*) like so:

```bash
find -print0 | sort -z | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' f; do [ -f "$f" ] && echo "$f is a file"; done
./1_with_newline
file.txt is a file
./2_with_space file.txt is a file
./3_with_tab    file.txt is a file
./4_normal_file.txt is a file
```

Answer (score 2):

Yup, you're missing something. You're listing files in the parent directory, but when you check whether it is a file or directory, you're still in the current directory - you have to modify it like this to work with parent directory:

```
for file in $(ls .. | sort) ; do
        if [ -d "../$file" ]
        then
                echo "$file is a directory"
        fi
        if [ -f "../$file" ]
        then
                echo "$file is a file"
        fi
done
```

However, as the comments indicate, this isn't necessarily the best way to go about this.