# Can you execute multiple commands in the shell without the use of '&&', '||' or ';'?

Tags: command-line, scripts, ls

Without the use of '&&', '||' and ';' - Can you write a 2-line Linux script that lists all files (even ones hidden) in the current directory and the parent of the working directory and the /boot directory (in this order), in long format?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/1446565

Answer (score 1):

With full path as required:

```
find . .. /boot -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec readlink -f {} +
```

or of instead you need the output of `ls -l`:

```
ls -la . .. /boot
```

Comment: This output doesn't make any sense, as it prefixes the current path in front of everything - and where to you see the requirement for full path?

Comment: You didn't answer from where you got the requirement for full path.

Comment: OP said `in long format` Maybe not well asked, but I guess it's full path

Comment: And I guess it's "long format" as stated in `man ls` with the `-l` switch. And now your output is recursive, listing all files in subdirectories, which wasn't asked for as well.. I'm just giving up, have fun!

Comment: Added `-maxdepth 1`

Comment: Thanks. I'll try that. I am however still confused.

Comment: What do you mean by confused?

Comment: Thought about using "ls -aln && ls -aln .. && ls -aln /boot" but again for my purposes I can't use '&&', '||' or ';'.

Comment: Have you tested my commands? Does it works?

Comment: basically I need a command that'll give the result of what the above (my above comment) command would've had I been able to just write that.

Comment: Yes I tried your command but unfortunately didn't return what I needed it to.

Comment: Your response is quite vague. Thanks to elaborate/paste on  https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin