# Why this func in xargs has error?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, functions

Why this coammand has error?
get_year func works.

```
xargs -I {} -r -n1 cp {} ${Dst}/videos/$(bash -c 'get_year {}')
```

errors

```
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '{}': No such file or directory
```

get_year func

```
get_year() {
ls -l --time-style=full $1 | tr -s ' ' | cut -d' ' -f6 | cut -d'-' -f 1 

}
export -f get_year
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're encountering is due to the placeholder `{}` not being expanded by `xargs`. To resolve this issue, you need to use the `-I` option correctly with `xargs`. The placeholder `{}` will be replaced by the input arguments passed to `xargs`
so it will look like this:

```
xargs -I {} -r -n1 bash -c 'cp "{}" "${Dst}/videos/$(get_year "{}")"' -- {}
```

Comment: Do not embed `{}` directly into shell code. That'll create a code injection vulnerability. See, e.g., https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/448449/70524 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/156008/70524

Answer (score 3):

##### Why?

The place holder/replace string e.g. `{}` should get replaced after the `xargs` command, even if improperly placed inside a single quoted Bash command string (*which can be dangerous ... See the remarks part below for explanation*) that will run in a sub-shell like e.g.:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'line1' 'line2' 'line3' | xargs -I {} -r -n1 bash -c 'echo "This is {}"'
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
```

Although, the proper and safer way is to pass it to the Bash script as a positional parameter like so:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'line1' 'line2' 'line3' | xargs -I {} -r -n1 bash -c 'echo "This is $1"' bash {}
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
```

That said, if you enclose the Bash script in a command substitution(*`$( ... )`*) syntax, then the command substitution part gets executed before the `xargs` command i.e. before the place holder `{}` is assigned any value and therefore, it will be processed as a literal `{}`.

If you enable command traces in Bash like so:

```
$ set -x
```

Then run without command substitution:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'line1' 'line2' 'line3' | xargs -I {} -r -n1 bash -c 'echo "This is {}"'
+ xargs -I '{}' -r -n1 bash -c 'echo "This is {}"'
+ printf '%s\n' line1 line2 line3
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
```

And then, with command substitution:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'line1' 'line2' 'line3' | xargs -I {} -r -n1 $(bash -c 'echo "This is {}"')
+ printf '%s\n' line1 line2 line3
++ bash -c 'echo "This is {}"'
+ xargs -I '{}' -r -n1 This is '{}'
xargs: This: No such file or directory
```

It should be obvious to you now that the `xargs` command is trying to execute and pass arguments to the **output** of the command substitution, because command substitution gets [expanded early on the command line in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html).

##### How?

Although moving the command substitution part inside the Bash command string so it will be run in a sub-shell(*Command substitution*) from withing another sub-shell(*Bash command string*) from within anothr sub-shell(*[created for that part of the pipe line](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html)*) ... Therefore, delaying its execution(*away from the perspective of the current shell's command line parsing*) until the place holder `{}` has been assigned a value by `xargs` ... Although that might work, but I would rather not do it.

*Not discussing your obvious parsing of `ls`'s output in your function and the probable piping of similar output by `ls` as well which I'd rather not recommend ... Please see [more explanation about that here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1446578).*

What I would recommend instead is to not use a pipeline and not use `xargs`, but rather use a shell loop to process your files like so:

```bash
for f in *; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    y=$(get_year "$f")
    cp -v -- "$f" "${Dst}"/videos/"$y"
    fi
  done
```

##### Remarks

- **Probably Too Technical Notice**: The place holder/replace string in `xargs` option `-I`e.g. `{}` in your case is not actually expanded per-se i.e. by the shell, but rather replaced by `xargs` and its replacement put in "the same" position on the command line itself by writing to standard output ... That can be observed with `strace` like e.g. so:

  ```
  $ printf '%s\n' 'line' | strace -f -e 'write' xargs -I {} echo {}
  strace: Process 37373 attached
  [pid 37373] write(1, "line\n", 5line
  )       = 5
  [pid 37373] +++ exited with 0 +++
  --- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=37373, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
  +++ exited with 0 +++
  ```

  ... And that's why it could be dangerous to include the place holder/replace string as is in shell scripts as it will allow for command injection which could be malicious or destructive.

  Compare for example:

  ```
  $ printf '%s\n' '; seq 1 9' '; echo ~' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo {}'

  1
  2
  3
  4
  5
  6
  7
  8
  9

  /home/ubuntu
  ```

  ... where commands get executed e.g. `seq 1 9` and shell expansion happens e.g. `~` expanded to your home directory ... Imagine what could happen if, for example, one of the injected commands happened to be `; rm -rf ~`

  Compare that with when the place holder/replace string is properly passed to the shell script as a positional parameter:

  ```
  $ printf '%s\n' '; seq 1 9' '; echo ~' | xargs -I {} bash -c 'echo "$1"' bash {}
  ; seq 1 9
  ; echo ~
  ```

  ... where no injected commands get executed and no shell expansion happens.
- The options `-I` and `-n` are mutually exclusive so you might not want to use them together although if the argument to `-n` is `1` then probably no harm will be done ... Also `-I` implies `-L 1` so you might not need to use `-n 1` at all.